# Receiving - SMTP instance has no attribute error

Tags: python, smtp, gmail, smtplib

I am trying to automate sending emails to a list of clients using a python script. It worked perfectly before they made it so you can't use the less secure app on 30th May 2022. I added the 2FA password and approved my computer. I am now receiving the error
*server.send_message(message)
AttributeError: SMTP instance has no attribute 'send_message'* when I try to run my code. Any ideas on how to fix this? I will attach the code below and have of course taken out sensitive information.

**Python Code**

```
            MY_ADDRESS = "****@gmail.com"         # Email Address
            MY_PASSWORD = "****Password****"      # Emails 2FA Pass
            RECIPIENT_ADDRESS = ['****@gmail.com', '****@gmail.com']  # Recipient Address

            HOST_ADDRESS = 'smtp.gmail.com'   
            HOST_PORT = 587                         


            import smtplib
            from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
            from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
            from email.mime.text import MIMEText


            # Connection with the server
            server = smtplib.SMTP(host=HOST_ADDRESS, port=HOST_PORT)
            server.starttls()
            server.login(MY_ADDRESS, MY_PASSWORD)

            # Creation of the MIMEMultipart Object
            message = MIMEMultipart()

            # Setup of MIMEMultipart Object Header
            message['From'] = MY_ADDRESS
            message['To'] = ", ".join(RECIPIENT_ADDRESS)
            message['Subject'] = "Test Email - July"

            # Creation of a MIMEText Part
            textPart = MIMEText("Hello **** & ****,\n\nAttached below is your test bill for the month of July 2022. \n\nBest,\Your Management", 'plain')

            # Creation of a MIMEApplication Part
            filename = "Test Bill - Billy.pdf"
            filePart = MIMEApplication(open(filename,"rb").read(),Name=filename)
            filePart["Content-Disposition"] = 'attachment; filename="%s' % filename

            # Parts attachment
            message.attach(textPart)
            message.attach(filePart)

            # Send Email and close connection
            server.send_message(message)
            server.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
import smtplib
from email.utils import formataddr
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText


msg = MIMEMultipart()
body_part = MIMEText('Write you text here.')
user = 'xxxx@gmail.com'
password = 'xxxx'
msg['Subject'] = 'You subject'
msg['From'] = formataddr(('yyyyy', 'xxxx@gmail.com'))
msg['To'] = 'yyyy@gmail.com'
msg.attach(body_part)
smtp_obj = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465)
smtp_obj.login(user, password)
smtp_obj.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
smtp_obj.quit()
```

Update: How to attach a file to your email:

Just add the following lines to the script above.

```
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
path = './../' #The path of your file.

with open(path + filename,'rb') as file:    
        msg.attach(MIMEApplication(file.read(), Name='filename'))
```

Comment: It worked and sent the email. How would I send to multiple users using this method? Additionally, how can I attach a pdf file stored locally to send as well as I did in my original code? Thank you so much for the help

Comment: I updated the script to attach files.

Comment: Regarding multiple email sending please try this and let me know if it works: msg['Subject']='yyyy@gmail.com, xx@gmail.com'  and then change msg['To'] to msg['To'].split(',')

Comment: That worked perfectly! I didnt add it to the msg['Subject'], I added it to the msg['To'] section but it worked. Thank you for the help.